# How to split a list into pairs in all possible ways

Tags: python

I have a list (say 6 elements for simplicity)

```
L = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

and I want to chunk it into pairs in **ALL** possible ways. I show some configurations:

```
[(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5)]
[(0, 1), (2, 4), (3, 5)]
[(0, 1), (2, 5), (3, 4)]
```

and so on. 
Here `(a, b) = (b, a)` and the order of pairs is not important i.e.

```
[(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5)] = [(0, 1), (4, 5), (2, 3)]
```

The total number of such configurations is `1*3*5*...*(N-1)` where `N` is the length of my list.

How can I write a generator in Python that gives me all possible configurations for an arbitrary `N`?

Comment: You may want to look at that standard module `itertools` if you haven't already.  The functions there should be able to help with this problem (possibly the `permutations`, `combinations` or `product` functions).

Comment: If order is not important, you should probably use sets or frozensets.

Comment: In the language of combinatorics, you want to generate all *perfect matchings* on a given set (in a complete graph).

Answer (score 162):

Take a look at [`itertools.combinations`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.combinations(range(6), 2))
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 5)]
```

Comment: That's not what the question asks ... but does happen to be what I was looking for :)

Comment: Why is this the most upvoted answer? It does not seem to answer the question.

Comment: It answers the question of most people that come to this site.

Comment: @Halbort It does answer the title though, so it helps a lot of people. Plus, this is surely the main problem OP had anyway. Here's the combinations of *an iterable*, now chunk it however you want.

Comment: @OJFord I don't actually think this answers the title: I think "splitting" the list implies that we end up with disjoint subsets of the original. I would argue that this answer is answering, "How to generate all possible pairs from a list". I suppose, however, it could still be true that this is the answer most people are looking for.

Answer (score 63):

I don't think there's any function in the standard library that does exactly what you need. Just using `itertools.combinations` can get you a list of all possible individual pairs, but doesn't actually solve the problem of all valid pair combinations.

You could solve this easily with:

```
import itertools
def all_pairs(lst):
    for p in itertools.permutations(lst):
        i = iter(p)
        yield zip(i,i)
```

But this will get you duplicates as it treats (a,b) and (b,a) as different, and also gives all orderings of pairs. In the end, I figured it's easier to code this from scratch than trying to filter the results, so here's the correct function.

```
def all_pairs(lst):
    if len(lst) < 2:
        yield []
        return
    if len(lst) % 2 == 1:
        # Handle odd length list
        for i in range(len(lst)):
            for result in all_pairs(lst[:i] + lst[i+1:]):
                yield result
    else:
        a = lst[0]
        for i in range(1,len(lst)):
            pair = (a,lst[i])
            for rest in all_pairs(lst[1:i]+lst[i+1:]):
                yield [pair] + rest
```

It's recursive, so it will run into stack issues with a long list, but otherwise does what you need.

```
>>> for x in all_pairs([0,1,2,3,4,5]):
    print x

[(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5)]
[(0, 1), (2, 4), (3, 5)]
[(0, 1), (2, 5), (3, 4)]
[(0, 2), (1, 3), (4, 5)]
[(0, 2), (1, 4), (3, 5)]
[(0, 2), (1, 5), (3, 4)]
[(0, 3), (1, 2), (4, 5)]
[(0, 3), (1, 4), (2, 5)]
[(0, 3), (1, 5), (2, 4)]
[(0, 4), (1, 2), (3, 5)]
[(0, 4), (1, 3), (2, 5)]
[(0, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3)]
[(0, 5), (1, 2), (3, 4)]
[(0, 5), (1, 3), (2, 4)]
[(0, 5), (1, 4), (2, 3)]
```

Comment: By default Python has a return stack 1000 calls deep. You are recursing on pairs of digits, so this should not be an issue until your list is almost 2000 items long. At only 50 items you get more than 5*10^31 combinations; you will run into billion-year computations long before stack depth becomes an issue.

Comment: This is the classic way to write this.

Comment: It seems that there is a problem with this answer (running Python 2.7.11). The first line of the output when running exactly the same code returns: `[(0, 1), (2, 3), 4]`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm sure the answer has been written with the best intentions, but it is incorrect for all input lists of odd length

Comment: @MoritzWalter What were you expecting the output to be for input lists of odd length? To me, the question doesn't even make sense if the lists had odd length, as it couldn't be split into pairs.

Comment: @Zack you can still split a list of odd length it into pairs, you'll just have a leftover list item

Comment: @MoritzWalter I suppose that is one way that you could interpret the question for lists of odd length, but it is possibly confusing. If you can leave items out for the chunking, then wouldn’t that mean that you could pick any number of pairs? Anyway I just meant that surely the way the question has been written it’s safe to assume that the list has an even length because the behaviour for the other case hasn’t been mentioned in the question.

Comment: I have to do a similar thing but for a list of 400 unique items. To print every possible list would certainly take too long and is not even what I need. Is there a way to output the list produced by a particular iteration e.g. in the example above, just the 4th list [(0,2),(1,3),(4,5)] ? - please redirect me if this is the wrong place to ask this question.

Comment: @SH `all_pairs` in this function is a *generator function*; notice how it uses the keyword `yield` rather than `return`. The cool thing is that if you are only interested in the first few lists, then it will only produce the first few lists. For instance: `g = all_pairs([1,2,3,4,5]); a = next(g); b = next(g); c = next(g); d = next(g)` Now `a,b,c,d` are the first 4 lists; the remaining lists have not been computed at all. Instead of repeatedly using `next`, you can use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice).

Comment: @SH For instance `from itertools import islice; d = next(islice(all_pairs(range(400)), k, k+1))` Now `d` is the *k*th list from `all_pairs`, and only the first *k* lists have been generated.

Answer (score 32):

How about this:

```
items = ["me", "you", "him"]
[(items[i],items[j]) for i in range(len(items)) for j in range(i+1, len(items))]

[('me', 'you'), ('me', 'him'), ('you', 'him')]
```

or

```
items = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6]
[(items[i],items[j]) for i in range(len(items)) for j in range(i+1, len(items))]

[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 3), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 5), (3, 6), (5, 6)]
```

Comment: well, it doesn't group the sets of pairs

Answer (score 17):

Conceptually similar to @shang's answer, but it does not assume that groups are of size 2:

```
import itertools

def generate_groups(lst, n):
    if not lst:
        yield []
    else:
        for group in (((lst[0],) + xs) for xs in itertools.combinations(lst[1:], n-1)):
            for groups in generate_groups([x for x in lst if x not in group], n):
                yield [group] + groups

pprint(list(generate_groups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2)))
```

This yields:

```
[[(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5)],
 [(0, 1), (2, 4), (3, 5)],
 [(0, 1), (2, 5), (3, 4)],
 [(0, 2), (1, 3), (4, 5)],
 [(0, 2), (1, 4), (3, 5)],
 [(0, 2), (1, 5), (3, 4)],
 [(0, 3), (1, 2), (4, 5)],
 [(0, 3), (1, 4), (2, 5)],
 [(0, 3), (1, 5), (2, 4)],
 [(0, 4), (1, 2), (3, 5)],
 [(0, 4), (1, 3), (2, 5)],
 [(0, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3)],
 [(0, 5), (1, 2), (3, 4)],
 [(0, 5), (1, 3), (2, 4)],
 [(0, 5), (1, 4), (2, 3)]]
```

Answer (score 9):

A non-recursive function to find all the possible pairs where the order does not matter, i.e., (a,b) = (b,a)

```
def combinantorial(lst):
    count = 0
    index = 1
    pairs = []
    for element1 in lst:
        for element2 in lst[index:]:
            pairs.append((element1, element2))
        index += 1

    return pairs
```

Since it is non-recursive you won't experience memory issues with long lists.

Example of usage:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(combinantorial(my_list))
>>>
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 5)]
```

Comment: This is the same as itertools.combinations

Answer (score 8):

My boss is probably not going to be happy I spent a little time on this fun problem, but here's a nice solution that doesn't need recursion, and uses `itertools.product`. It's explained in the docstring :). The results seem OK, but I haven't tested it too much.

```
import itertools


def all_pairs(lst):
    """Generate all sets of unique pairs from a list `lst`.

    This is equivalent to all _partitions_ of `lst` (considered as an indexed
    set) which have 2 elements in each partition.

    Recall how we compute the total number of such partitions. Starting with
    a list

    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

    one takes off the first element, and chooses its pair [from any of the
    remaining 5].  For example, we might choose our first pair to be (1, 4).
    Then, we take off the next element, 2, and choose which element it is
    paired to (say, 3). So, there are 5 * 3 * 1 = 15 such partitions.

    That sounds like a lot of nested loops (i.e. recursion), because 1 could
    pick 2, in which case our next element is 3. But, if one abstracts "what
    the next element is", and instead just thinks of what index it is in the
    remaining list, our choices are static and can be aided by the
    itertools.product() function.
    """
    N = len(lst)
    choice_indices = itertools.product(*[
        xrange(k) for k in reversed(xrange(1, N, 2)) ])

    for choice in choice_indices:
        # calculate the list corresponding to the choices
        tmp = lst[:]
        result = []
        for index in choice:
            result.append( (tmp.pop(0), tmp.pop(index)) )
        yield result
```

cheers!

Comment: a more precise name should be `all_pairings` and `xrange` should be replaced by `range` in Python 3.

Comment: The implementation is clean, but it doesn't work for list with odd number of elements.

Answer (score 6):

Try the following recursive generator function:

```
def pairs_gen(L):
    if len(L) == 2:
        yield [(L[0], L[1])]
    else:
        first = L.pop(0)
        for i, e in enumerate(L):
            second = L.pop(i)
            for list_of_pairs in pairs_gen(L):
                list_of_pairs.insert(0, (first, second))
                yield list_of_pairs
            L.insert(i, second)
        L.insert(0, first)
```

Example usage:

```
>>> for pairs in pairs_gen([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]):
...     print pairs
...
[(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5)]
[(0, 1), (2, 4), (3, 5)]
[(0, 1), (2, 5), (3, 4)]
[(0, 2), (1, 3), (4, 5)]
[(0, 2), (1, 4), (3, 5)]
[(0, 2), (1, 5), (3, 4)]
[(0, 3), (1, 2), (4, 5)]
[(0, 3), (1, 4), (2, 5)]
[(0, 3), (1, 5), (2, 4)]
[(0, 4), (1, 2), (3, 5)]
[(0, 4), (1, 3), (2, 5)]
[(0, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3)]
[(0, 5), (1, 2), (3, 4)]
[(0, 5), (1, 3), (2, 4)]
[(0, 5), (1, 4), (2, 3)]
```

Answer (score 4):

I made a small test suite for all the compliant solutions. I had to change the functions a bit to get them to work in Python 3. Interestingly, the fastest function in PyPy is the slowest function in Python 2/3 in some cases.

```
import itertools 
import time
from collections import OrderedDict

def tokland_org(lst, n):
    if not lst:
        yield []
    else:
        for group in (((lst[0],) + xs) for xs in itertools.combinations(lst[1:], n-1)):
            for groups in tokland_org([x for x in lst if x not in group], n):
                yield [group] + groups

tokland = lambda x: tokland_org(x, 2)

def gatoatigrado(lst):
    N = len(lst)
    choice_indices = itertools.product(*[
        range(k) for k in reversed(range(1, N, 2)) ])

    for choice in choice_indices:
        # calculate the list corresponding to the choices
        tmp = list(lst)
        result = []
        for index in choice:
            result.append( (tmp.pop(0), tmp.pop(index)) )
        yield result

def shang(X):
    lst = list(X)
    if len(lst) < 2:
        yield lst
        return
    a = lst[0]
    for i in range(1,len(lst)):
        pair = (a,lst[i])
        for rest in shang(lst[1:i]+lst[i+1:]):
            yield [pair] + rest

def smichr(X):
    lst = list(X)
    if not lst:
        yield [tuple()]
    elif len(lst) == 1:
        yield [tuple(lst)]
    elif len(lst) == 2:
        yield [tuple(lst)]
    else:
        if len(lst) % 2:
            for i in (None, True):
                if i not in lst:
                    lst = lst + [i]
                    PAD = i
                    break
            else:
                while chr(i) in lst:
                    i += 1
                PAD = chr(i)
                lst = lst + [PAD]
        else:
            PAD = False
        a = lst[0]
        for i in range(1, len(lst)):
            pair = (a, lst[i])
            for rest in smichr(lst[1:i] + lst[i+1:]):
                rv = [pair] + rest
                if PAD is not False:
                    for i, t in enumerate(rv):
                        if PAD in t:
                            rv[i] = (t[0],)
                            break
                yield rv

def adeel_zafar(X):
    L = list(X)
    if len(L) == 2:
        yield [(L[0], L[1])]
    else:
        first = L.pop(0)
        for i, e in enumerate(L):
            second = L.pop(i)
            for list_of_pairs in adeel_zafar(L):
                list_of_pairs.insert(0, (first, second))
                yield list_of_pairs
            L.insert(i, second)
        L.insert(0, first)

if __name__ =="__main__":
    import timeit
    import pprint

    candidates = dict(tokland=tokland, gatoatigrado=gatoatigrado, shang=shang, smichr=smichr, adeel_zafar=adeel_zafar)

    for i in range(1,7):
        results = [ frozenset([frozenset(x) for x in candidate(range(i*2))]) for candidate in candidates.values() ]
        assert len(frozenset(results)) == 1

    print("Times for getting all permutations of sets of unordered pairs consisting of two draws from a 6-element deck until it is empty")
    times = dict([(k, timeit.timeit('list({0}(range(6)))'.format(k), setup="from __main__ import {0}".format(k), number=10000)) for k in candidates.keys()])
    pprint.pprint([(k, "{0:.3g}".format(v)) for k,v in OrderedDict(sorted(times.items(), key=lambda t: t[1])).items()])

    print("Times for getting the first 2000 permutations of sets of unordered pairs consisting of two draws from a 52-element deck until it is empty")
    times = dict([(k, timeit.timeit('list(islice({0}(range(52)), 800))'.format(k), setup="from itertools import islice; from __main__ import {0}".format(k), number=100)) for k in candidates.keys()])
    pprint.pprint([(k, "{0:.3g}".format(v)) for k,v in OrderedDict(sorted(times.items(), key=lambda t: t[1])).items()])

    """
    print("The 10000th permutations of the previous series:")
    gens = dict([(k,v(range(52))) for k,v in candidates.items()])
    tenthousands = dict([(k, list(itertools.islice(permutations, 10000))[-1]) for k,permutations in gens.items()])
    for pair in tenthousands.items():
        print(pair[0])
        print(pair[1])
    """
```

They all seem to generate the exact same order, so the sets aren't necessary, but this way it's future proof. I experimented a bit with the Python 3 conversion, it is not always clear where to construct the list, but I tried some alternatives and chose the fastest.

Here are the benchmark results:

```
% echo "pypy"; pypy all_pairs.py; echo "python2"; python all_pairs.py; echo "python3"; python3 all_pairs.py
pypy
Times for getting all permutations of sets of unordered pairs consisting of two draws from a 6-element deck until it is empty
[('gatoatigrado', '0.0626'),
 ('adeel_zafar', '0.125'),
 ('smichr', '0.149'),
 ('shang', '0.2'),
 ('tokland', '0.27')]
Times for getting the first 2000 permutations of sets of unordered pairs consisting of two draws from a 52-element deck until it is empty
[('gatoatigrado', '0.29'),
 ('adeel_zafar', '0.411'),
 ('smichr', '0.464'),
 ('shang', '0.493'),
 ('tokland', '0.553')]
python2
Times for getting all permutations of sets of unordered pairs consisting of two draws from a 6-element deck until it is empty
[('gatoatigrado', '0.344'),
 ('adeel_zafar', '0.374'),
 ('smichr', '0.396'),
 ('shang', '0.495'),
 ('tokland', '0.675')]
Times for getting the first 2000 permutations of sets of unordered pairs consisting of two draws from a 52-element deck until it is empty
[('adeel_zafar', '0.773'),
 ('shang', '0.823'),
 ('smichr', '0.841'),
 ('tokland', '0.948'),
 ('gatoatigrado', '1.38')]
python3
Times for getting all permutations of sets of unordered pairs consisting of two draws from a 6-element deck until it is empty
[('gatoatigrado', '0.385'),
 ('adeel_zafar', '0.419'),
 ('smichr', '0.433'),
 ('shang', '0.562'),
 ('tokland', '0.837')]
Times for getting the first 2000 permutations of sets of unordered pairs consisting of two draws from a 52-element deck until it is empty
[('smichr', '0.783'),
 ('shang', '0.81'),
 ('adeel_zafar', '0.835'),
 ('tokland', '0.969'),
 ('gatoatigrado', '1.3')]
% pypy --version
Python 2.7.12 (5.6.0+dfsg-0~ppa2~ubuntu16.04, Nov 11 2016, 16:31:26)
[PyPy 5.6.0 with GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
% python3 --version
Python 3.5.2
```

So I say, go with gatoatigrado's solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
def f(l):
    if l == []:
        yield []
        return
    ll = l[1:]
    for j in range(len(ll)):
        for end in f(ll[:j] + ll[j+1:]):
            yield [(l[0], ll[j])] + end
```

Usage:

```
for x in f([0,1,2,3,4,5]):
    print x

>>> 
[(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5)]
[(0, 1), (2, 4), (3, 5)]
[(0, 1), (2, 5), (3, 4)]
[(0, 2), (1, 3), (4, 5)]
[(0, 2), (1, 4), (3, 5)]
[(0, 2), (1, 5), (3, 4)]
[(0, 3), (1, 2), (4, 5)]
[(0, 3), (1, 4), (2, 5)]
[(0, 3), (1, 5), (2, 4)]
[(0, 4), (1, 2), (3, 5)]
[(0, 4), (1, 3), (2, 5)]
[(0, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3)]
[(0, 5), (1, 2), (3, 4)]
[(0, 5), (1, 3), (2, 4)]
[(0, 5), (1, 4), (2, 3)]
```

Comment: Oops, didn't see shang's answer, which does the same thing... should I delete this one?

Comment: No need to delete, but shang's use of real variable names is better.

Answer (score 2):

```
L = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
answer = []
for i in range(len(L)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(L)):
        if (L[i],L[j]) not in answer:
            answer.append((L[i],L[j]))

print answer
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help:

> L = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>
> [(i,j) for i in L for j in L]

**output:**

`[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4), (4, 5), (5, 0), (5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5)]`

Comment: `(0, 0)` is not a pair from the list. `(0, 1)` and `(1, 0)` are equivalent

Answer (score 1):

This code works when the length of the list is not a multiple of 2; it employs a hack to make it work. Perhaps there are better ways to do this...It also ensures that the pairs are always in a tuple and that it works whether the input is a list or tuple.

```
def all_pairs(lst):
    """Return all combinations of pairs of items of ``lst`` where order
    within the pair and order of pairs does not matter.

    Examples
    ========

    >>> for i in range(6):
    ...  list(all_pairs(range(i)))
    ...
    [[()]]
    [[(0,)]]
    [[(0, 1)]]
    [[(0, 1), (2,)], [(0, 2), (1,)], [(0,), (1, 2)]]
    [[(0, 1), (2, 3)], [(0, 2), (1, 3)], [(0, 3), (1, 2)]]
    [[(0, 1), (2, 3), (4,)], [(0, 1), (2, 4), (3,)], [(0, 1), (2,), (3, 4)], [(0, 2)
    , (1, 3), (4,)], [(0, 2), (1, 4), (3,)], [(0, 2), (1,), (3, 4)], [(0, 3), (1, 2)
    , (4,)], [(0, 3), (1, 4), (2,)], [(0, 3), (1,), (2, 4)], [(0, 4), (1, 2), (3,)],
     [(0, 4), (1, 3), (2,)], [(0, 4), (1,), (2, 3)], [(0,), (1, 2), (3, 4)], [(0,),
    (1, 3), (2, 4)], [(0,), (1, 4), (2, 3)]]

    Note that when the list has an odd number of items, one of the
    pairs will be a singleton.

    References
    ==========

    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360220/
    how-to-split-a-list-into-pairs-in-all-possible-ways

    """
    if not lst:
        yield [tuple()]
    elif len(lst) == 1:
        yield [tuple(lst)]
    elif len(lst) == 2:
        yield [tuple(lst)]
    else:
        if len(lst) % 2:
            for i in (None, True):
                if i not in lst:
                    lst = list(lst) + [i]
                    PAD = i
                    break
            else:
                while chr(i) in lst:
                    i += 1
                PAD = chr(i)
                lst = list(lst) + [PAD]
        else:
            PAD = False
        a = lst[0]
        for i in range(1, len(lst)):
            pair = (a, lst[i])
            for rest in all_pairs(lst[1:i] + lst[i+1:]):
                rv = [pair] + rest
                if PAD is not False:
                    for i, t in enumerate(rv):
                        if PAD in t:
                            rv[i] = (t[0],)
                            break
                yield rv
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding in my own contribution, which builds on the great solutions provided by @shang and @tokland. My problem was that in a group of 12, I wanted to also see all the possible pairs when your pair size does not divide perfectly with the group size. For instance, for an input list size of 12, I want to see all possible pairs with 5 elements.

This snip of code and small modification should address that issue:

```py
import itertools

def generate_groups(lst, n):
    if not lst:
        yield []
    else:
        
        if len(lst) % n == 0:
        
        
            for group in (((lst[0],) + xs) for xs in itertools.combinations(lst[1:], n-1)):
                for groups in generate_groups([x for x in lst if x not in group], n):
                    yield [group] + groups
            
        else:
            
            for group in (((lst[0],) + xs) for xs in itertools.combinations(lst[1:], n-1)):
                group2 = [x for x in lst if x not in group]
                for grp in (((group2[0],) + xs2) for xs2 in itertools.combinations(group2[1:], n-1)):
                    yield [group] + [grp]
```

Thus, in this case, if I run the following snip of code, I get the results below. The final snip of code is a sanity check that I have no overlapping elements.

```py
i = 0
for x in generate_groups([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], 5):
    print(x)
    for elem in x[0]:
        if elem in x[1]:
            print('break')
            break
```

```py
>>>
[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8, 9, 10)]
[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8, 9, 11)]
[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8, 9, 12)]
[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8, 10, 11)]
[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8, 10, 12)]
[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8, 11, 12)]
[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 9, 10, 11)]
...
```

Answer (score -2):

Not the most efficient or fastest, but probably the easiest.  The last line is a simple way to dedupe a list in python.  In this case, pairs like (0,1) and (1,0) are in the output.  Not sure if you'd consider those duplicates or not.

```
l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
pairs = []
for x in l:
    for y in l:
        pairs.append((x,y))
pairs = list(set(pairs))
print(pairs)
```

Output:

```
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4), (4, 5), (5, 0), (5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5)]
```

Comment: Duplicate pairs in the list `(0, 1)` is the same pair as `(1, 0)`. See question