# How to create pairs in a list of elements with no repetition in Python?

Tags: python

How can I construct pairs between elements of a list with no repetition and no omission?

Say I have a list:

```
tickers = ['SPY','GLD','OIL'].
```

How can I form an array of pairs?  I want this output:

```
[('SPY, 'GLD'),('SPY','OIL'), ("GLD','OIL)]
```

Comment: You can look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360220/how-to-split-a-list-into-pairs-in-all-possible-ways

Comment: This answer perfectly solve my question. Thx!