# Find every combination of a list of integers split into exactly two subsets

Tags: python

Suppose I have a list of integers:

```
myList = [1,2,3,4]
```

How would one return every possible combination of these two subsets with Python.

For example, set [1,2,3,4] would produce
[1,2], [3,4] and [1,3], [2,4] and [1,4],[2,3]

Comment: And if you intend on generating both pairs from each combination (I can't entirely tell from your question), see [How to split a list into pairs in all possible ways](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360220/how-to-split-a-list-into-pairs-in-all-possible-ways) for inspiration.

Comment: Please see my edit for explanation as to why this is not a duplicate

Comment: "Every possible combination of these two subsets" doesn't make sense to me. Can you please add sample output?

Comment: Please see my example input and output

Comment: Then what exactly do you expect for `[1, 2, 3, 4]`? All of the n choose 2 combinations are given by `itertools.combinations`, as linked in the duplicate.For instance for your `[1,2,3]` example, `list(combinations([1,2,3], 2))` produces `[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]`.

Comment: Sorry I explained that wrong. Please see my outputs now. It is now explained properly

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5362528/4686625) from the second question I linked, as well as [this recursive answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5360442/4686625). You could probably improve them, even. There's a few other approaches below those on the same question.

Comment: This is actually still not what I mean. Suppose your list had 8 elements, we would return two sets each with 4 elements, then two sets with 4 elements in a different combination, etc until all combinations have been seen. We do not want to always return pairs

Comment: I ___really___ hope you're starting to see the importance of being clear with your question. Your question is effectively generating all `k`-subset partitions of equal size `i` for some `i` > 0 on an array `A`. Without the "equal size" restriction, this is a classical algorithm problem ([see here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1526/finding-all-k-subset-partitions)). Try and adapt it for your own purpose (the equality constraint) - it is too broad of a question to ask on Stack Overflow on its own anyways, it sounds an awful lot like homework.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`itertools` can give you all combinations of a list of size you define (here `n`):

```
import itertools

myList = [1,2,3,4]
n=3
for subset in itertools.combinations(myList , n):
    print(subset)
```

output:

```
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 4)
(1, 3, 4)
(2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: Why bother answering such an obvious duplicate?

Comment: This is exactly right.

Comment: @manbearpig1 ___How is this not exactly what we started with?___ `itertools.combinations`, as linked in the duplicate that you refuted before changing the problem entirely....

Comment: This is much different obviously

Comment: @manbearpig1 How? Please tell me how.