# all combination in list of lists without duplicates in python

Tags: python

let say I have a list of lists

```
[[a1, a2, a3], [b1, b2], [c1, c2, c3, c4]]
```

The number of lists in the list is not known in advance.

I want to have all combinations of elements from the different list, so

```
[a1, b1, c1], [a1, b1, c2], ..., [a3, b2, c4]
```

but if there common elements in the different list, all these combinations need to be deleted. So if for example, `a1 = c2`, then the combinations `[a1, b1, c2], [a1, b2, c2]` need to be deleted in the resulting list.

To get all possible combinations, you can use the answer on [All possible permutations of a set of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853212/all-possible-permutations-of-a-set-of-lists-in-python]), but can you automaticaly delete all combinations with common elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) `itertools.product`

```
 all_combinations = itertools.product(elements)
```

2) `filter` with lambda

```
filtered_combinations = filter(lambda x: len(x) != len(set(x)), all_combinations)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the [Cartesian Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of your lists. Use [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), and filter the elements to make sure none are equal:

```
from itertools import product

for combo in product(*input_lists):
    if len(set(combo)) != len(combo):  # not all values unique
        continue
    print(*combo)
```

I'm assuming that by *`a1 = c2`* you mean that all values in the combination need to be *unique*, the above tests for this by creating a set from the combination. If the set length is smaller than the combination length, you had repeated values.

You can put this filter into a generator function:

```
def unique_product(*l, repeat=None):
    for combo in product(*l, repeat=repeat):
        if len(set(combo)) == len(combo):  # all values unique
            yield combo
```

then use `for unique in unique_product(*input_lists):`

You can also use the [`filter()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) to achieve the same, but that incurs a function call for each combination produced.

Answer (score 2):

As the other guys said, you can do with itertools but you may need to drop duplicates:

```py
import itertools

L = [1,2,3,4]
combos = list(itertools.combinations(L, 2))
pairs = [[x, y] for x in combos for y in combos if not set(x).intersection(set(y))]
list(set(sum(pairs, [])))
```

And then the you will have this as output:

```
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (3, 4), (2, 4)]
```

[EDIT]

Inspired on the answer provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42924469/8357763