# Pandas - change next row on single column based on the fuzzy wuzzy result of comparing row[i] with row[i+1]

Tags: python, pandas, fuzzywuzzy

I have the next DataFrame(df) in pandas: (This is just an example the real DF is more than 2000 rows and more than 20 names)

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Andrea Gonzlez |
| 2 | Andrea Glz |
| 3 | Andrea Glez |
| 4 | Lineth Arce |
| 5 | lineth a |
| 6 | lineth aerc |

I want to compare row 1 name with row 2 name and if they are >80% ratio, then row 2 gets changed to name in row 1. So in the end i will have a column where i only have different names of each one.

What I did is i created a list with the names = ['Andrea Glz', 'Lineth Arce'] and then create a function:

```
def compare(x): 
   for i in names:
      ratio = fuzz.token_set_ratio(i,x)
      if ratio > 80:
        return i
```

Then use the next code and rewrite the column with the matched result from the names list:

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].apply(compare)
```

I get the desired result but takes a lot of processing time.
Is there an easier and faster way of doing this?

Desired result table:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Andrea Gonzlez |
| 2 | Andrea Gonzlez |
| 3 | Andrea Gonzlez |
| 4 | Lineth Arce |
| 5 | Lineth Arce |
| 6 | Lineth Arce |

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

1> Find unique names from the dataframe

2> Find unique 2 combinations of the name. Use `itertools`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49219469/all-combination-in-list-of-lists-without-duplicates-in-python)

```
---Name1-------|----Name2-------|
Andrea Gonzlez | Andrea Gonzlez |
Andrea Gonzlez | Lineth Arce    |
...
---------------|----------------|
```

3> Find similarity of two columns

```
---Name1-------|----Name2-------|----similarity---|
Andrea Gonzlez | Andrea Gonzlez |    100          |
Andrea Gonzlez | Lineth Arce    |     20          |
...
---------------|----------------|-----------------|
```

4> Select the rows where similarity is less than `80`% and from them only select `Name1`

Comment: Thank you, it may work like that but its a lot more coding than the one i already have. What im looking to get is how can i loop through one column and use the "next" row in the same operation. How to compare the row im using with the one before.

Comment: Looping is a single threaded process mostly therefore the processing time isn't expected to reduce drastically compare to the current method you are already doing.

Comment: Thank you. I'll keep investigating the way of doing this as fast as I can. I appreciate your help