# Split a list into all pairs in all possible ways

Tags: python, list, partitioning

I am aware of many posts with the similar questions and have been through all of them. However, I am not able to do what I need.

I have list say `l1=[0,1,2,3,4]` which I want to partition into pair of tuples like following:

```
 [(0, 1), (2, 3), 4],
 [(0, 1), (2, 4), 3],
 [(0, 1), (3, 4), 2],
 [(0, 2), (1, 3), 4],
 [(0, 2), (1, 4), 5],
 [(0, 2), (3, 4), 1],
 [(0, 3), (1, 2), 4],
 [(0, 3), (2, 4), 1],
 [(0, 3), (1, 4), 2],
 [(0, 4), (1, 2), 3],
 [(0, 4), (1, 3), 2],
 [(0, 4), (2, 3), 1]
```

I tried a solution from the post [how-to-split-a-list-into-pairs-in-all-possible-ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360220/how-to-split-a-list-into-pairs-in-all-possible-ways).

```
def all_pairs(lst):
    if len(lst) < 2:
        yield lst
        return
    a = lst[0]
    for i in range(1,len(lst)):
        pair = (a,lst[i])
        for rest in all_pairs(lst[1:i]+lst[i+1:]):
            yield [pair] + rest
```

I get the following output:

```
[(0, 1), (2, 3), 4]
[(0, 1), (2, 4), 3]
[(0, 2), (1, 3), 4]
[(0, 2), (1, 4), 3]
[(0, 3), (1, 2), 4]
[(0, 3), (1, 4), 2]
[(0, 4), (1, 2), 3]
[(0, 4), (1, 3), 2]
```

I find that there are some combinations which are missing from the list which I want.

I would appreciate any suggestion?

Comment: May I ask what is the use case for such a niche programming problem?

Comment: Is your first list *complete* as to what you expect? Is the order within the pair irrelevant, and the order of the pairs as well? Both answers currently yield much longer answers.

Comment: Actually, why does 0 never appear last? Should you also have `[(1, 2), (3, 4), 0]`, `[(1, 3), (2, 4), 0]`, and others?

Comment: Yes, @NickT is right. I should also have other combinations which he mentioned.

Comment: Is your input always going to have 5 values? If you expect to take variable lengths, sometimes odd, sometimes even, it might be easier if you allowed the odd one to show up as something like `(4, None)` or `(4,)` instead of a bare `4`.

Comment: I agree @NickT . For even number of elements, the solution in the my question works quite well. But in my problem, I have odd number of elements in the list. What you suggested is interesting? Let me try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `itertools.permutations` and filter out duplicates using `frozenset`:

```
In [173]: d = {frozenset([frozenset(x[:2]), frozenset(x[2:4]), x[-1]]) for x in itertools.permutations(l1, 
     ...: len(l1))}

In [174]: d2 = [sorted(x,  key=lambda x: (not isinstance(x, frozenset), x)) for x in d]

In [175]: sorted([[tuple(x[0]), tuple(x[1]), x[-1]] for x in d2])
Out[175]: 
[[(0, 4), (2, 3), 1],
 [(1, 2), (0, 3), 4],
 [(1, 2), (0, 4), 3],
 [(1, 2), (3, 4), 0],
 [(1, 3), (0, 2), 4],
 [(1, 3), (0, 4), 2],
 [(1, 3), (2, 4), 0],
 [(1, 4), (0, 2), 3],
 [(1, 4), (0, 3), 2],
 [(2, 3), (0, 1), 4],
 [(2, 3), (1, 4), 0],
 [(2, 4), (0, 1), 3],
 [(2, 4), (0, 3), 1],
 [(3, 4), (0, 1), 2],
 [(3, 4), (0, 2), 1]]
```

Comment: It looks like based on his expected list that he wants to ignore order, so `[(0, 1), (2, 3), 4] == [(0, 1), (3, 2), 4] == [(2, 3), (0, 1), 4]`

Comment: @NickT Based on OP's desired output, it is not exhaustive? I'll look for some clarification from OP.

Comment: What would be missing from his list if order inside and between pairs was ignored?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ `[(0, 1), (2, 3), 4]` is duplicate of `[(0, 1), (3, 2), 4]`. Actually, ordering inside a tuple is irrelevant. How do I get rid of these duplicates?

Comment: @NickT I used a frozenset and got rid of those duplicates.

Comment: @Pankaj Please confirm that this is what you want. The other answer will not give you combinations other than `[(0, ...), ...]`

Comment: Thanks @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ. Still `[(1, 2), (0, 3), 4]` is duplicate of `[(0, 3), (1, 2), 4]` and some others.

Comment: Learned `itertools.permutations` from your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `itertools.permutations` and then use a list comprehension to create pairs out of the first 4 items in each permuation:

```
l1=[0,1,2,3,4]
from itertools import permutations
l2 = permutations(l1)
l3 = [[(x[0], x[1]), (x[2], x[3]), x[4]] for x in l2]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[[(0, i), tuple(item for item in l if item not in {0, i ,j}), j] for i in range(1, 5) for j in [item for item in l if item not in {0, i}]]

[[(0, 1), (3, 4), 2],
 [(0, 1), (2, 4), 3],
 [(0, 1), (2, 3), 4],
 [(0, 2), (3, 4), 1],
 [(0, 2), (1, 4), 3],
 [(0, 2), (1, 3), 4],
 [(0, 3), (2, 4), 1],
 [(0, 3), (1, 4), 2],
 [(0, 3), (1, 2), 4],
 [(0, 4), (2, 3), 1],
 [(0, 4), (1, 3), 2],
 [(0, 4), (1, 2), 3]]
```