# Make only identical pairs in python list

Tags: python, list

How to create pairs in python list .
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
i want to compare (1,2),(3,4) (5,6)

identical pairs comparison

how can we loop through all the pairs

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` and slice the input list every two items with different starting points:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

list(zip(lst[::2], lst[1::2]))
```

output: `[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]`

Comment: @Daniel `pairwise` is great, but this is not the expected output. OP wants to group by 2, without duplication.

Comment: Agreed. That's why I use `similar` results in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to take the list and create all possible pairs.
To do that, you should use itertools.

Take a look at the following topic:
[How to split a list into pairs in all possible ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360220/how-to-split-a-list-into-pairs-in-all-possible-ways).

```py
import itertools
list(itertools.combinations(range(6), 2))
#[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 5)]
```

Comment: I don't want all possible pairs just a pair of 2 elements and then next two-element  and so on

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
def chunks(lst, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from lst."""
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):yield lst[i:i + n]    
sublist = [x for x in chunks(list, 2)]
for x in sublist:
    if x.__len__() > 1:continue
    else:sublist.remove(x)
print(sublist)
```

Output:

`[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]`

Answer (score 0):

It will use a moving cursor for slicing to get the value.

```py
def func(l):
    prev_i, i = 0, 2
    while True:
        current = l[prev_i: i]
        if len(current) < 2:
            break
        yield current
        prev_i, i = i, i + 2


print(list(func([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])))
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```